# If the localization of a ring at each prime ideal is Noetherian, does this imply that ring is Noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian, localization

1. If the localization $R_p$ of a ring $R$ at each prime ideal $p$ in A is Noetherian, does this imply that $A$ is Noetherian?
2. What we call such rings which is not Noetherian but localization at each prime ideal is Noetherian ?
3. Can somebody provide me any counterexample of (1) and also a good reference?

Comment: There even exist nonNoetherian rings whose localizations at all primes are all *fields*. (The Boolean ring at the linked question is such a ring.)

Comment: @user26857 Do we have some special name in mathematics literature for such rings?

Comment: @Anoopsingh : maybe "locally noetherian" ? This is just a guess.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the quotient of a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables with coefficients in a field by the ideal generated by all monomials of degree 2